# Angular - Writing unit test case for switchMap

Tags: angular, jasmine

below are my two service methods

```
    getCountries(offset: number) {
          let url = this.configManagerService.countriesApiUrl;
          const httpHeaders = this.getHeaders();
          return this.httpClient.get(url + offset, { headers: httpHeaders });
        }
        
    getAllCountries(offset: number = 0, resultOld: any[] = []) {
      return this.getCountries(offset).pipe(
      
        //not getting covered
        switchMap((result: any) => {
          offset = result.length > 0 ? offset + result.length : -1;
          return offset >= 0
            ? this.getAllCountries(offset, [...resultOld, ...result])
            : of(resultOld);
        //not getting covered
        
        })
      );
    }
```

I was able to write unit test case which covered `getCountries` function, but not able to understand how can I cover the code which I mentioned between the comments regarding `switchMap`. Tried to google it but not able to find anything which suits my requirements. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of one case.

```
it('returns resultOld if result length is zero', (done: DoneFn) => {
  const resultOld = [];
  spyOn(service, 'getCountries').and.returnValue(of(resultOld));
  service.getAllCountries(2, resultOld).subscribe(results => {
    expect(results.length).toBe(0);
    done();
  });
});

it('calls getAllCountries over and over until converge', (done: DoneFn) => {
  const resultOld = [{ name: 'USA' }];
  spyOn(service, 'getCountries').and.returnValue(of(resultOld));
  service.getAllCountries(-1, resultOld).subscribe(results => {
    expect(results.length).toBe(1);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Ali, I tried this but getting 'WARN: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. I am not sure what is this error about.

Comment: Hey Vamsi, sorry about that, I read it wrong. It seems that you have a stackoverflow where `getAllCountries` is calling itself over and over again. I changed the test to return an empty array. I also added a test for your 2nd scenario as well. It is tough for me to reason about because I don't know what offset is but I hope this comment helps you.

Comment: Hello Ali, I am still getting the same error. Can we break the loop after first iteration?

Comment: I just removed 2nd test case, it is causing the error. The 1st one just worked fine. Thanks Ali.